# Flyway & Hibernate : Cannot populate data to initial database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

In a Spring Boot app, I am using Hibernate and 2 tables is created properly. However, I also need to insert data one of these tables and for this purpose I thought I should use Flyway.

Then I just added insert clauses to the Flyway and use the following parameters for Hibernate and Flyway in application.properties:v

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update # also tried none

spring.flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
spring.flyway.schemas=demo-db
spring.flyway.user=root
spring.flyway.password=******
```

I have not used Flyway for initializing database and I am not sure if I can use Flyway with Hibernate as I mentioned above. Or, should I disable Hibernate table creation and create another migration script for table creation?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that Hibernate does not automatically create tables. Additionally, if using Spring Boot, Flyway will run before the service using hibernate has started. As a result, your Flyway script are interacting with a table that does not exist.

The recommended way to do this is to use Flyway to manage both your database structure, your create tables etc, and static data. This will mean your database is versioned and provisioned ready for your service and hibernate can connect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I had also some problems when using `data.sql`. Although it works and inserted data to the created table without Flyway, then when running the app 2nd tim it gives error as it tries to insert the same records again. So, flyway is the best way to avoid also this kind of situations and keep data on each running of the data, right?

Comment: On the other hand, what about using the annotations also on Hibernate side (I mean Entity classes)? Of course I will create all the constraint, indexes, sequence, etc. via flyway migration scripts, but I also think that it is good idea to add all of corresponding annotations to the Entity side? What do you suggest?

Comment: Any reply please?

Answer (score 2):

If you use flyway only for `insert data` don't do that. Try to use this:

[With Hibernate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts):

> In addition, a file named import.sql in the root of the classpath is executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is, if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop).

[With Basic SQL Scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts):

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your JDBC DataSource or R2DBC ConnectionFactory and initialize it (DML scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: schema.sql and data.sql